# How to return array list in lua program?

Tags: list, lua, return

I want to return the list of records from retrieving data from database in lua program.

```
local function getListFromDatabase()

    local select_stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM list")
    for row in select_stmt:nrows() do
    print(row.id, row.name, row.icon)
    end

end
```

Actually, I am new to lua programing
I want to return a list of records, I am not getting idea how to return a list

Please help me out of this

Thank you,
madan mohan

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the rows then just do this:

```
  local function getListFromDatabase()
     local select_stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM list")
     return select_stmt:rows()
  end
```

then you can use it like this:

```
  local rows = getListFromDatabase()
```

I refer you to the user manual: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html

Comment: How to print this rows using for loop, Please could you explain.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua, you use a table to pass an array.  See the fine [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html) book entry.