# How to return a list and how to acess those values in lua

Tags: database, sqlite, lua

local function getList()

```
        local select_stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM list")
        return select_stmt:rows();
    end


    local rows = getList();

     --**here i need to print the rows list, how I can print using for loop**

--************************************************
    **here I want to fetch single record, I am unable to fetch and print it?**

    local function getListRecord(listId)


      local select_stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM list where id = ?")
        select_stmt:bind_names{ id = listId }
        return select_stmt:get_unames()-- i AM GETTING ERROR HERE

    end

    local row = getListRecord(3);

--I am unable to get the row here, please help me
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344068/how-to-return-array-list-in-lua-program

Answer (score 0):

This looks the same as the question you asked yesterday
[How to return array list in lua program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344068/how-to-return-array-list-in-lua-program)

```
for line,tblLine in pairs(rows) do
   for key,data in pairs(tblLine) do
     print(key,data)
   end
end
```

If you want to return a single row from the list and you know the index use

```
row = rows[3]
```

As suggested in the other responses, you need to review the table section of the Programming in Lua book as this is key to doing anything in Lua.

Comment: Yes, learning the language you're using is fundamental. You need to learn the ability of reading documentation and learning for yourself, instead of just blindingly ask for help. I suggest you to read [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/), at least chapters 2, 4, 5 and 7. Here's [a link to LuaSQLite's docs](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki) too, for your reference.